# R lapply convert to integer but keep rownames

Tags: r

I am trying all afternoon to do this:

Convert a dataframe to integer, which works fine:
cts <- lapply(cts, function(x) as.integer(x))

But afterwards my rownames(cts) = Null. I want to keep my rownames.
How do I exclude them from this conversion?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Show us some reproducible data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` to preserve the attributes i.e rownames here.

```
cts[] <- lapply(cts, as.integer)
```

Using `mtcars` as reproducible example.

```
df <- mtcars
rownames(df)
df <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
rownames(df)
df <- mtcars
df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
rownames(df)
```

Comment: ohh wow thanks so much!! so whenever i want to save the "settings" from before i do this "[]" ?

Comment: Yes, it should save it most of the times.

Comment: You can also use `lapply(cts, as.integer)` as R recognizes `as.integer` as a function

Comment: Very helpful, i didnt know :)

Comment: You would use the `function(x)` format if you define a custom-made function